# Select added class name in Sass

Tags: css, sass

I'm adding an 'down' class name to a div using js.

Is it possible in Sass to hit the 'down' class while styling the div

```
    <div class="insight">
    </div> 

    //add down class with js when clicked
    <div class="insight down">
    </div> 


    .insight{
        background: gray;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;

        &:down{
            background: red;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try `&.down` which should compile into `.insight.down` meaning having both `.insight` and `.down`

Comment: `&:down{` should be `&.down{`

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, you've used the wrong selector. In CSS `:` is a pseudo-element selector, for example `span:hover`, `a:clicked`, and so on.

You want an element with two shared classes, so `.` is fine:

```
&.down {}
```

will do exactly what you need. As you've noted `&` in SASS is the current scoped element so this will compile to

```
.insight.down
```

Which is valid CSS and exactly what you want.